# Andorid custom view `onMeasure` not setting the desired width and height

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I've created an InnerCustomView and although I'm overriding `onMeasure`, the view height is not set as the desired height.

Here is some context.

I have a `CustomView`. This view has a container (`RelativeLayout`) and inside here I have 4 `InnerCustomViews` plus two guidelines that I need to place in the container. For simplicity, I'm only showing here one of those `InnerCustomViews` because I can't manage to set this view to my width and height requirements.

This is the `CustomView` layout relevant information:

```
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/grey">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            ....
             />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image">
            <View
                android:id="@+id/guide"
                android:layout_width="12dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
                .......
            <...InnerCustomView
                android:id="..."
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/guide"
                android:background="@color/green"
                ... />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

In `CustomView` I'm doing this:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    //Based on the container size I calculate the InnerCustomView desiredSize
    innerCustomView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(desiredSize, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(desiredSize, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
}
```

The `InnerCustomView` only has an `ImageView` and a `TextView`

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/grey">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have this in `InnerCustomView`:

```
    public class InnerCustomView extends LinearLayout {

        //Default constructors and other stuff.

        @Override
        public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

            measureChildren(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            //Here I'm loging the values in widthMeasureSpec and heightMeasureSpec and I can see that they are the desiredSize

            setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }
```

If you look at the image bellow, except height, my layout is as expected. The vertical guide (dark green) is in the correct place and the `InnerCustomView` is at it's right. The problem is that the width and height are not the ones I've passed when I called `measure`.
Width takes the available space and height also thus taking the whole height of the view (light green)
On the other hand, the `InnerCustomView` content has the `desiredSize` (grey).

Any ideia why is this happening?

I've tried to invalidate() the view, requestLayout(), forceLayout() but with no success.

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution? If then please post it here as I have the same problem.